# Club the UI model and DB model in C#

Tags: c#, model

I'm having a client, and it sending the following Signature to the Library

**Client UI Signature** :

```
namespace Library.Model
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string streetName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Library DB Structure**:

```
namespace Library.Data
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public Address AddressInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public string streetName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here I'm doing the mapping process from Client UI model to DB Structured model. How could I use the DB structured model as like Client model instead of the Client model.

Kindly assist me how efficiently we can share the DB Structured model in Client?

> Note: But the Client the Signature should be

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string streetName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Kindly refer [Update a class property based on another Property of a calss properties value in the Setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663807/update-a-class-property-based-on-another-property-of-a-calss-properties-value-in) - I need the solution similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use PersonViewModel to make this and it will be like you mention

```
public class PersonViewModel 
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string streetName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Make join and file this object

```
PersonViewModel persons = new PersonViewModel ();
```

I wish it will help you :)